# Adjust a function's argument in R

Tags: r

How do I put all `XMR` arguments from below dataset as argument inside a function at once?

I could do like this:

```
f1 <- function(X1,X2,X3,X4, XM1, XMR0, XMR01, XMR02, XMR03, XMR4){
  
  x2<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("XMR"))
  x2<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$XM1 - x2, paste0(names(x2), "_PA")))
  x3<-select(x2,X1,X2,X3,X4,XM1,ends_with("PA"))

return(x3)
 }
```

However, if I had a lot of `XMR`, it would be bad to put several `XMR`. Is there any easier way to do it?

```
  df1 <- structure(
  list(
    X1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
    X2 = c("4","3","1","2"),
    X3 = c("1", "2","3","2"),
    X4 = c("1", "2","3","2"),
    XM1 = c(200, 300, 200, 200),
    XMR0 = c(300, 300, 300, 300),
    XMR01 = c(300, 300, 300, 300),
    XMR02 = c(300,300,300,300),
    XMR03 = c(300,300,300,300),
    XMR04 = c(300,250,350,350)),row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: your function showed argument 'X4' which is not in the 'df1' columnname

Comment: @akrun, I tweaked it there, thanks for seeing. See that I have a function `f1` with the arguments of `df1`. My idea is therefore not to mention `df1` at all, just the columns of `df1`.

Comment: In that case, the code I showed should work as it is working fine with your function (there are some parts inside the function that looks hardcoded i.e. `df1$XM1` instead of the argument passed

Comment: Right! One thing, inside the function, I mentioned `df1`, but I didn't want to mention it, just the arguments, does this cause any problems?

Comment: Yes, it will cause issue because `select` needs a data.frame object name which is not passed as input.  I would have data name as an argument and do the selection inside

Comment: That's what I thought too. I'll accept your answer, but I wanted to take the opportunity to ask you some questions, if that's ok. It's like this: I have a problem where I have a function that generates prediction, which works perfectly, which is like this: `f1 <- function(df1, X1,X2,X3,X4, ...)`. In this case, df1 represents several values, as it is a data.frame equal to the one in the question. However, I need that instead of doing that, I would like to pass the data that will be used to the function, which comes from `df1`. How would you do it?

Comment: Suppose your function is. `f1 <- function(df1, ...){}` then you may pass the argument as `do.call(f1, c(list(df1 = df1), as.list(colnames(df1))))`

Comment: I understood more or less. Would it be possible to put a brief example, or maybe I'll ask a new question?

Comment: You may rewrite the function as in my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier with `do.call` (assuming the arguments to the functions are in the same order as the columns of the data)

```
do.call(f1, as.list(colnames(df1)))
 X1 X2 X3 XM1 XMR0_PA XMR01_PA XMR02_PA XMR03_PA XMR04_PA
1  1  4  1 200    -100     -100     -100     -100     -100
2  1  3  2 300       0        0        0        0       50
3  1  1  3 200    -100     -100     -100     -100     -150
4  1  2  2 200    -100     -100     -100     -100     -150
```

---

The function can be also written as

```
f2 <- function(data){ 
  
  data %>% 
     transmute(across(matches("^X\\d+$")),
      XM1, across(starts_with("XMR"), ~ XM1 - .x, 
        .names = "{.col}_PA" )) 
  }
```

and then we use as

```
> f2(df1)
  X1 X2 X3 XM1 XMR0_PA XMR01_PA XMR02_PA XMR03_PA XMR04_PA
1  1  4  1 200    -100     -100     -100     -100     -100
2  1  3  2 300       0        0        0        0       50
3  1  1  3 200    -100     -100     -100     -100     -150
4  1  2  2 200    -100     -100     -100     -100     -150
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, but I didn't want to call my df1 database. I just wanted to use the attributes of df1 database.

Comment: @LivviaSouza perhaps you can pass the column names only? then `do.call(f1, as.list(colnames(df1)))` without your function, it is very difficult to know what you really wanted

Comment: @LivviaSouza without the function showed, it is not clear whether it can string as inputs or only use unquoted column names?

Comment: I'm going to do the function and I'll insert it in the question for you to see, a moment.

Comment: @LivviaSouza or try by converting to `symbol` i.e. ` do.call(f1, lapply(as.list(colnames(df1)), as.name))`